# How to access object array using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, internationalization

console.log (dict) will give you

{"click here:":{"message":"点击这里"},"apply":{"message":"应用"},"a translation test!":{"message":"js翻译示例！"},"tabLanding":"欢迎","tabSetup":{"message":"安装"}}

I want tabSetup appear like 安装 in html 
here is the html code:

```
<li class="tab_setup"><a href="#" i18n="tabSetup"></a></li>
```

what i see is it does not shows correctly just showed as [object Object]
it should showed as 安装

here is my java-script. Thanks

```
 var dict = {};
    var systemLang = navigator.language.toLowerCase().slice(0,2);
    $(function () {
      registerWords();
      switch(getCookieVal("lang")) {
        case "en" :
          setLanguage("en");
          break
        case "zh" :
          setLanguage("zh");
          break
        default:
          setLanguage(systemLang);
      }
      console.log (dict);

      console.log(JSON.stringify(dict));


    // 切换语言事件
      $("#enBtn").bind("click", function () {
        setLanguage("en");
      });

      $("#zhBtn").bind("click", function () {
        setLanguage("zh");
      });

      // $("#applyBtn").bind("click", function () {
      //   alert(__tr("a translation test!"));
      // });
    });

    function setLanguage(lang) {
      setCookie("lang=" + lang + "; path=/;");
      translate(lang);
    }

    function getCookieVal(name) {
      var items = document.cookie.split(";");
      for (var i in items) {
        var cookie = $.trim(items[i]);
        var eqIdx = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var key = cookie.substring(0, eqIdx);
        if (name == $.trim(key)) {
          return $.trim(cookie.substring(eqIdx + 1));
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

    function setCookie(cookie) {
      var Days = 30; //此 cookie 将被保存 30 天
      var exp = new Date(); //new Date("December 31, 9998");
      exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + Days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      document.cookie = cookie+ ";expires=" + exp.toGMTString();
    }

    function translate(lang) {
      if(sessionStorage.getItem(lang + "Data") != null){
        dict = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(lang + "Data"));
      }else{
        loadDict();
      }

      $("[i18n]").each(function () {
        switch (this.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
          case "input":
            $(this).val(__tr($(this).attr("i18n")));
            break;
          default:
            $(this).text(__tr($(this).attr("i18n")));
        }
      });
    }

    function __tr(src) {
      return (dict[src] || src);
    }

    function loadDict() {
      var lang = (getCookieVal("lang") || "en");
      $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "/lang/"+lang + ".json",
        success: function (msg) {
          dict = msg;
          sessionStorage.setItem(lang + 'Data', JSON.stringify(dict));
        }
      });

    }
    // 遍历所有lang属性的标签赋值
    function registerWords() {

        $('[i18n]:not(.i18n-replaced').each(function() {
            var element = $(this);

            element.html(translate(element.attr('i18n')));
            element.addClass('i18n-replaced');

      });
    }
```

It works if json file like "tabSetup": "Set up". .It does not works if json file like "tabSetup": { "message": "Set up" }

Comment: the function `translate` does not return anything, is that a problem?

Comment: I do not think so.. translate function must be a problem in term of not give a good object.. but it does not need to return anything

Comment: It makes the line `element.html(translate(element.attr('i18n')));` seem strange to me

Comment: It works if json file like   "tabSetup": "Set up". .It does not works if json file like     "tabSetup": {
        "message": "Set up"
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function __tr has error, repair like this

```
function __tr(src) {
    return (dict[src].message || src);
}
```

Comment: I bet this answer is close, maybe try `return dict[src] ? dict[src].message : src`

Comment: IrkenInvader your answer works. lex.xu , IrkenInvader you guys are amazing. i truly impressed by your skill